# State values resetting after onSubmit even if not successful

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a form, and if I do a submit and it returns an error, I programmed it to show me where the errors are. After fixing only the errors and I submit it fails because the states are being reseted and having empty values being sent to the api.
I will show some code below:

```
const AddProject = (props) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    projectName: '', projectIdentifier: '', description: '', startDate: '', endDate: '', errors: {},
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.errors) {
      setValues({ errors: props.errors });
    }
  }, [props.errors]);

  const onChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    console.log(values);
    setValues({ ...values, [name]: value });
  };

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newProject = {
      projectName: values.projectName,
      projectIdentifier: values.projectIdentifier,
      description: values.description,
      startDate: values.startDate,
      endDate: values.endDate,
    };

    props.createProject(newProject);
  };
```

### create project action below

```
const createProject = (project) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/project', project);
    window.history.back();
  } catch (e) {
    dispatch({
      type: GET_ERRORS,
      payload: e.response.data
    });
  }
};

export default createProject;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
useEffect(() => {
if (props.errors) {
  let temp = { ...values };
  temp.errors = props.errors;
  setValues(temp);
}
}, [props.errors]);
```

When using react hooks, you need to get the previous state and then set new values. When you setting just props.errors, it is removing all other key values from your state.

Hope this helps

Comment: Done correcty. Thank you. Though it gives me a warning
 ```
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'values'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. You can also do a functional update 'setValues(v => ...)' if you only need 'values' in the 'setValues' call"
```

Comment: This is an ESLint warning. You can disable it.